# Mapeo de Agregados DDD

Tags: php, symfony, ddd

Estoy creando una aplicación en Symfony/DDD (aunque el lenguaje es indiferente en ) y tengo algunas dudas conceptuales que no consigo resolver. Apenas encuentro información clara sobre lo que voy a preguntar.

Mi aplicación por el momento tiene un Bounded Context llamado `Dashboard` con 2 agregados:

```
 1. User
 2. Notification
```

Y éste es su código:

```js
class User extends AgregateRoot implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    private UuidValueObject $id;

    private string $name;

    private string $surname;

    private ?string $secondSurname;

    private array $roles;

    private UserEmail $email;

    private UserPlainPassword $plainPassword;

    private UserPlainPassword $repeatedPlainPassword;

    private UserHashedPassword $lastHashedPassword;

    private UserHashedPassword $hashedPassword;

    private UserProvider $provider;

    private \DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    private \DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt;

    private bool $active;  
 }
```

```js
class Notification
{
    private NotificationId $id;
    
    private NotificationAction $action;

    private NotificationUserSource $userSource;

    private Collection $userTargets;

    private bool $visualized;

    private DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    private DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt;

    private bool $active;
}
```

Y aquí sus mapeos a la base de datos:

```html
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping">
    <entity name="App\Dashboard\User\Domain\Agregate\User">
        <embedded name="id" class="App\Dashboard\User\Domain\Agregate\UserId" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <field name="name" column="name" type="string" length="30" />
        <field name="surname" column="surname" type="string" length="30" />
        <field name="secondSurname" column="secondSurname" type="string" length="30" nullable="true" />
        <field name="roles" column="roles" type="json" />
        <embedded name="email" class="App\Dashboard\User\Domain\Agregate\UserEmail" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <embedded name="hashedPassword" class="App\Dashboard\User\Domain\Agregate\UserHashedPassword" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <embedded name="provider" class="App\Dashboard\User\Domain\Agregate\UserProvider" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <field name="createdAt" column="created_at" type="datetime_immutable" />
        <field name="updatedAt" column="updated_at" type="datetime_immutable" nullable="true" />
        <field name="active" column="active" type="boolean" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

```html
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping">
    <entity name="App\Dashboard\Notification\Domain\Agregate\Notification">
        <embedded name="id" class="App\Dashboard\Notification\Domain\Agregate\NotificationId" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <embedded name="action" class="App\Dashboard\Notification\Domain\Agregate\NotificationAction" use-column-prefix="false" />
        <many-to-one field="userSource" target-entity="App\Dashboard\Notification\Domain\Agregate\NotificationUserSource\NotificationUserSource">
            <join-column name="user_source" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-many field="userTargets" target-entity="App\Dashboard\Notification\Domain\Agregate\NotificationUserTarget\NotificationUserTarget">
            <join-table name="notification_user_targets">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="notification_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
        </many-to-many>
        <field name="visualized" column="visualized" type="boolean" />
        <field name="createdAt" column="created_at" type="datetime_immutable" />
        <field name="updatedAt" column="updated_at" type="datetime_immutable" nullable="true" />
        <field name="active" column="active" type="boolean" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Mi duda viene por lo siguiente:

Cuando necesito utilizar un agregado dentro de otro agregado (una relación) como en el caso de `Notification` como debería afrontarlo:

- Si creo una propiedad con una instancia del otro agregado directamente pienso que es un enfoque erróneo ya que tendría acceso a todas las propiedades y métodos de User en éste caso sin necesitarlo, lo que podría dar lugar a llamar a uno de éstos métodos o propiedades erróneamente.
- Lo que me lleva al segundo enfoque. Creo un nuevo agregado `NotificationUserSource` con sólo las propiedades y métodos que necesito, aquí el código:

```js
class NotificationUserSource
{
    private UuidValueObject $id;

    private string $name;

    private string $surname;

    private string $secondSurname;
}
```

Éste segundo enfoque me lleva a un error al crear las migraciones ya que al mapear tanto el agregado `User` cómo el agregado `NotificationUserSource` al intentar crear la migración con el ORM recibo un error indicando que la tabla `User` ya existe, algo solucionable pero que implica hacer cosas raras como crear un proyecto secundario con entidades tradicionales sólo para ejecutar las migraciones o ponerle nombres falsos a las tablas hasta crear las migraciones, cosa inadmisible cuando tienes una gran cantidad de agregados y relaciones.

Por otra parte recalcar que `Notification` y `User` son agregados independientes porque la notificación no es creada por un usuario, sino que puede que por un admin o por el propio sistema. De hecho el propio Agregado `Notification` tiene otra relación con `User` que es una colección de los usuarios que reciben la notificación.

Ésto es solo un ejemplo y me ha pasado en más ocasiones. Me gustaría saber cómo abordais vosotros ésto y si mis enfoques son erróneos.

Comment: Tú puedes tener una clase DTO por cada entidad, poniendo en esas DTO solamente las propiedades que quieres exponer en la capa externa. Esto te permitirá trabajar con una arquitectura limpia y tener un código optimizado aplicando conceptos como *hydration*.

Comment: Ya tengo DTOs, no uno por cada entidad sino uno por cada caso de uso separados entre consultas y comandos para separar las request con CQRS. Aquí pregunto sobre los agregados y el mapeo de éstos y cómo utilizar la misma entidad en diferentes agregados con DDD sin que falle el mapeo.